# ExpandableRecyclerAdapter keeps data in between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm having difficulty using the [bignerdranch's ExpandableRecyclerView](https://github.com/bignerdranch/expandable-recycler-view). I'm about to get it to work on a fragment (see pics 1 and 2). However when I select a different fragment with a different layout, the data seems to stay in the ExpandableRecyclerView (see pics 3 and 4).

(I don't have enough rep to post individual links so the pics are in a [imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbxYS.jpg)-sorry!)

Here's my ExpandableRecyclerAdapter

```
public class myExpandRecylerAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<TitleParentViewHolder, TitleChildViewHolder> {

LayoutInflater mInflater;
assignment_class myAssignment;
myQueueTask myQueueTask;
Dialog dialog;
Calendar myCalendar;
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;
boolean DoneFlag = false;

public myExpandRecylerAdapter(Context context, List<ParentObject> parentItemList) {
    super(context, parentItemList);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}



@Override
public TitleParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_parent, viewGroup, false);
    return new TitleParentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public TitleChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_child, viewGroup, false);
    return new TitleChildViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindParentViewHolder(TitleParentViewHolder titleParentViewHolder, int i, Object o) {
    ParentViewClass title = (ParentViewClass) o;
    titleParentViewHolder.tvParent.setText(title.getTitle());

}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(final TitleChildViewHolder titleChildViewHolder, int i, Object o) {
    // o instanceof class can be used to determine the class type and template this adapter


    if (o instanceof assignment_class) {
        Log.d("instanceof","assignment_class");
        myAssignment = (assignment_class) o;
        titleChildViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(myAssignment.ass_name);
        titleChildViewHolder.tvTime.setText(myAssignment.TimeLeft());

        titleChildViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final assignment_class ModifiedAssignment = myAssignment;


                dialog = new Dialog(titleChildViewHolder.itemView.getContext());
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.assignment_dialog);
                dialog.show();
                Log.d("onClick", "Child: " + myAssignment.toString());


                // Set the textView at the top to the ass_name to indicate which assignment is being modified
                TextView Name = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                Name.setText(myAssignment.ass_name);


                Spinner DropDown = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spDropDown);

                // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
                ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(titleChildViewHolder.itemView.getContext(), R.array.class_list, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
                staticAdapter
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                // Apply the adapter to the spinner
                DropDown.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

                DropDown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Log.v("item", (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                        myAssignment.class_id = position;
                        Log.d("Set", myAssignment.class_id.toString());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

                // Initialize for DatePicker
                myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

                // Adapter
                date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                          int dayOfMonth) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

                        //Set textview
                        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                        ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDate)).setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
                    }

                };


                final TextView etDate = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);


                // Default to today
                String myFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
                ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvDate)).setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));


                // OnClick will open the dialogue for DatePicker
                etDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        new DatePickerDialog(dialog.getContext(), date, myCalendar
                                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
                    }
                });


                final TextView etTime = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.etTime);
                //Default time
                etTime.setText("00:00");


                // OnClick will open the dialogue for TimePicker
                etTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;

                        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(dialog.getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                                etTime.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                            }
                        }, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Calendar.MINUTE, false);
                        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                        mTimePicker.show();
                    }
                });


                final Button Done = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bDone);

                Done.setText("NOT DONE");
                Done.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (!DoneFlag) {
                            Done.setText("DONE");
                            DoneFlag = true;
                        } else {
                            Done.setText("NOT DONE");
                            DoneFlag = true;
                        }
                    }
                });

                Button Cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bCancel);
                Button Confirm = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bConfirm);
                Confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        ModifiedAssignment.ass_id = myAssignment.ass_id;
                        ModifiedAssignment.ass_name = ((TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvName)).getText();
                        ModifiedAssignment.class_id = 0; //TODO: This

                        // We have to convert etDate to Date
                        SimpleDateFormat parser_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        try {
                            ModifiedAssignment.due = parser_date.parse(etDate.toString() + " " + etTime + ":00");
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        ModifiedAssignment.date_assigned = myAssignment.date_assigned;
                        ModifiedAssignment.done = ((((Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bDone)).getText() == "DONE"));
                        ModifiedAssignment.weight = 99; //TODO: This aswell

                        myQueueItem item = null;
                        try {
                            item = new myQueueItem(new assignment_class(myAssignment, ModifiedAssignment));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        item.setMode("EDIT");
                        myQueue.getInstance().addQueueItem(item);

                    }
                });

                Cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    if (o instanceof myQueueTask) {
        myQueueTask = (myQueueTask) o;
        titleChildViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(myQueueTask.toString());
        titleChildViewHolder.tvTime.setText("time");

    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who runs into this problem the the solution is really simple but it's worth understanding the problem. In my ExpandableRecyclerAdapter you can see that I'm attempting to make it a template by using

```
if (o instanceof assignment_class)
```

However, I did not take into account my TitleCreator class responsible for creating each "row" which holds a list of the ParentViewClass which is responsible for the children (the dropdown items).

the solution is as follows:

```
static TitleCreator _titleCreator; 
private static List<?> ListOfObjects,OldList;
List<ParentViewClass> ClassNameArrayList;

public TitleCreator(Context context) {
    ClassNameArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    OldList = ListOfObjects;
    if (DetermineType() == RecylerAdapter.typeOfObjectsList.ASSIGN_CLASS) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfObjects.size(); i++) {
            ParentViewClass ParentView = new ParentViewClass(((assignment_class) ListOfObjects.get(i)).ass_name.toString());
            ClassNameArrayList.add(ParentView);
        }
    }
    if (DetermineType() == RecylerAdapter.typeOfObjectsList.QUEUETASK) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListOfObjects.size(); i++) {
            ParentViewClass ParentView = new ParentViewClass((ListOfObjects.get(i)).toString());
            ClassNameArrayList.add(ParentView);
        }
    }
}

 public static TitleCreator get(Context context, List<?> classList) {
    ListOfObjects = classList;
    if (_titleCreator == null || OldList != classList)
        _titleCreator = new TitleCreator(context);

   return _titleCreator;
}

//This lets us template RecyclerAdapter so
public RecylerAdapter.typeOfObjectsList DetermineType() {
    //Since we don't know the type, we have to deduce it. This is done by comparing the 0th element to expected types
    if (!ListOfObjects.isEmpty()) {
        if (ListOfObjects.get(0) instanceof myQueueTask)
            return RecylerAdapter.typeOfObjectsList.QUEUETASK;
        if (ListOfObjects.get(0) instanceof assignment_class)
            return RecylerAdapter.typeOfObjectsList.ASSIGN_CLASS;
    }
    if (!ListOfObjects.isEmpty()) {
        Log.d("ClassType", ListOfObjects.get(0).getClass().toString() + " has not been defined in TitleCreator.java");
    } else {
        Log.d("TitleCreator", "Encountered a unknown class type. You're probably not seeing anything so go to TitleCreator.java to define what you want to view ");
    }
    return RecylerAdapter.typeOfObjectsList.NAN;
}

public List<ParentViewClass> getAll() {
    return ClassNameArrayList;
}


public enum typeOfObjectsList {
    ASSIGN_CLASS, QUEUETASK, NAN
}
```

The line

```
OldList = ListOfObjects;
```

is called when a new TitleCreator(context) is called. This method is called in two scenarios:
1) if (**_titleCreator == null** || OldList != classList) due to short circuit evaluation it will initially evaluate to _titleCreator = null since it has not been initiated.

2) if (_titleCreator == null || **OldList != classList**) this will be evaluated if there is an already existing _titleCreator and OldList (which is set to classlist when a new TitleCreator is created) is equal to the List passed in the arguments.

While I'm not to familiar with software design I think the problem lies in that I was using TitlerCreator as a [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so the information was saved between fragments.